# Lot of confusion about GCD and serial queues

Tags: ios, multithreading, queue, grand-central-dispatch

My app does a lot of writing/reading from the SQLite DB and I'd like it to execute all of these on another thread, so that the Main thread is not blocked.
But all these DB operations have to be executed one after another, or it won't work.

For what I understand, I should use a serial queue, and add all the tasks to it.
If this is it, how to create a global serial queue and add tasks to it from whatever view I'm in?

Or maybe I didn't get it at all, so I need someone to point me to the right direction.
Thanks.

Comment: By the way, using a serial queue to coordinate database interactions from different threads is not uncommon, but a queue is not often used for performance reasons (as most database interactions are sufficiently fast). If you have some database interaction that isn't responding nearly instantaneously, you might want to take a look at that. (For example, some are unaware that the use of a transaction can dramatically improve performance if issuing a series of `UPDATE` statements. Or sometimes a judicious index can really improve performance.) Use a queue if needed, but it's generally not needed.

Comment: In my app there is a moment, when it is writing some 15000 records to the DB, that the UI is blocked for about two seconds. This is on the simulator. I'm afraid that on a real device (iPhone 4 for example) it would be worst. The same happens when it's reading all those records, but the blocking time is usually around 1 second. I'll look into transactions and indexes though. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As *Ashley Mills* suggested, you can create GCD queue:

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("SQLSerialQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    // ...
});
```

But another option is to use `NSOperationQueue`, which I prefer:

```
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1;
queue.name = @"SQLSerialQueue";
[queue addOperationWithBlock:^{
    // ...
}];
```

`NSOperationQueues` are built above GCD queues and allow you to **wait for running operations to finish** (something like converting async task to sync).
You can also create subclasses of `NSOperation` for tasks you perform frequently and add them easily to the queue.

Another advantage of `NSOperationQueues` is class method `+currentQueue`, which is hardly accessible in GCD environment.

On the other side, `NSOperationQueue` is missing *barrier* operations found in GCD. In the end, all differences can be achieved in the other framework, but with some little or more work.

---

If you decide to use GCD, but don't like its C interface, check my Objective-C wrapper: [Grand Object Dispatch](https://github.com/iMartinKiss/Grand-Object-Dispatch) ;)

Comment: Operation queues are fine, but GCD can wait for operation to finish (`dispatch_sync`), suspend (`dispatch_suspend`), and resume (`dispatch_resume`). Operation queues really excel where you need the ability to cancel operations or where you have concurrent queue where the ability to establish dependencies or constrain the degree of concurrency, none of which apply here. If you prefer operation queue over GCD, that's fine, but the advantages in this scenario are negligible, IMHO.

Comment: In practice, my experience is that barring usual circumstances the overhead of NSOperationQueue is not often noticable. I've often said and heard, "Use the highest level abstraction that gets the job done." Between GCD and NSOpQ use whatever you're more comfortable with, until you have a reason to do otherwise. OP is perhaps not feeling super comfy with GCD so if NSOpQ gets it done, why not?

Comment: I generally feel that GCD and NSOQ are equivalently high level abstractions, despite one of them being in C. I agree with the general point that if either one works fine for your particular situation, use whichever feels best to you, though.

Comment: @Rob You are right, you can schedule synchronous blocks with GCD, but by _waiting_ for operations I meant that with `NSOQ` you can schedule an asynchronous operation and later decide you want to wait for it. I found this to be very useful. Of course, you can achieve the same with GCD semaphores, but with some more coding.

Comment: What I have to mention is, that `NSOQ` is missing _barrier_ operations from GCD (`dispatch_barrier_async`). It may be possible to achieve the same result using dependencies, but in GCD it's ready to use.

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do to create a serial queue is:

```
dispatch_queue_t myQueue = dispatch_queue_create("myqueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
```

Perhaps look at using a singleton object that has `myQueue` as a property that can be accessed from anywhere in the app.

Answer (score 1):

Speaking from my own experience, you don't want to try to thread your database access too much without using a framework to handle it for you. I would suggest looking into [FMDatabaseQueue](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb).

Comment: +1 `FMDatabaseQueue` is great solution. Use it normally when you need synchronous interaction with your database, and dispatch it asynchronously to any background queue when you need asynchronous activity (and `FMDatabaseQueue` will coordinate the database interaction  for you). Great suggestion.